# How to Convert XML message to Binary in WSO2 ESB

Tags: mongodb, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

I am  trying to implement a proxy service that will read a `xml` file and save into `MongoDB`. But `MongoDB` doesn't support `xml` out of the box. I am trying to convert the `xml payload` to `binary` and then insert into MongoDB. Similarly, I have to retrieve the `binary` from MongoDB and convert into xml again.
I have already written `WSO2 DSS` service to insert and retrieve data from MongoDB.
Can anyone please help me figure out the message `builder or formatter` and required `properties` for `WSO2 ESB` to achieve the behaviour? I didn't found any sample on internet.

Comment: MondoDB is not designe to save xml file. Why you don't convert xml to json and save it in WSO2DSS.

Comment: Anyway you might consider to use base64 coding of xml to string and save it in mongo, with some identifier

Comment: I am using the approach, encode the xml and save it to mongo. But when I retrieve the content from mongo it looks very hard to decode.

Comment: Normally any encoder goes with decoder. I assume you convert xml to string replacing symbol on entities like in here http://coderstoolbox.net/string/#!encoding=xml&action=encode&charset=us_ascii
Use the same method to decode back